# Is it possible to exclude entry from search index?

Tags: search

I have some pages that I want to exclude from search results. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean entire sections you could define which sections you want to display like this:

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.craft.entries.section('section1, section2, section3').search(query).order('score') %}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create an array of ids to exclude and then use the `not` filter:

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set idsToExclude = [14,15] %}
{% set idsToExcludeString = idsToExclude|join(', not ') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score').id('and, not ' ~ idsToExcludeString) %}
```